# docker socker at /var/run/docker.sock with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have an issue where a few tools, Portainer for example, can't find the docker socket on AWS.

I have some setup scripts that were run to set various containers.

On MacOS, it works without problems.
On a CentOS box, no problem as well.

On CentOS / AWS, containers cannot connect to the docker socket.

I am talking about a local unsecured connection to /var/run/docker.sock

What could be different on AWS?

I can see the socket:

```
➜  run ls -ld /var/run/docker*
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root   200 Nov 27 14:04 /var/run/docker
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     4 Nov 27 14:03 /var/run/docker.pid
srw-rw-r-- 1 root docker   0 Nov 27 14:03 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: How you try to connect? Is it ECS or ec2?

Comment: It’s EC2; trying to put /car/run/docker.sock in portainer, like on the other systems. It doesn’t even auto detect like like on the others

Comment: `docker run -it -p 8000:8000 -p 9000:9000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data portainer/portainer` this worked for me cnetos AWS.

Comment: that's what I have; but it's not just portainer, other tools can't connect to the socket too; and when I check /var/run, it's there

Comment: There's nothing special about AWS in this regard, as @Adiii hints.  Providing a [mcve] of a specific setup that doesn't work would be very helpful.  (Just remember that any user or program that can access the Docker socket has unrestricted root access to the host.)